# Did Deadpool fight Boba Fett?

Tags: star-wars, marvel, comics, deadpool, boba-fett

I found an image on the web and I was curious as to where it was from, and whether Deadpool really did fight Boba Fett in a comic.

[image: In the style of an inspirational poster with a black border, a positive word and a pithy caption, is a picture of Deadpool (right side of the picture throwing a kick at Boba Fett's head with his right side right leg, blocking a bullet with a strangely puny sword in his right hand) fighting Boba Fett (left, blocking Deadpool's kick with his oddly massive left fist while firing a bizarre gun with his right); in the background Deadpool is whispering sweet nothings in Boba Fett's ear. The inspirational word is "Friends" and the caption reads "Who needs them when you have a picture of Boba Fett fighting Deadpool." It is not made clear why Deadpool has 2 right legs.]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Source: [http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/FightClub/news/?a=5919](https://web.archive.org/web/20150101020340/http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/FightClub/news/?a=5919)

It seems as though it is simply an art/drawing/depiction of the two fighting.

Comment: I agree with this. I often find images like this on the internet with many characters inside which have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: Note that the image originally on this page, http://s487.photobucket.com/albums/rr234/MartialLewis/?action=view%C2%A4t=BobaFettvsDeadpool.gif has also disappeared, and doesn't appear to be archived.

Answer (score 12):

He recently did in the lastest ERB :). Of course it is not canon.

[Deadpool vs Boba Fett. Epic Rap Battles of History - Bonus Battle!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g708PmJAbuI)

Comment: Add cool as that is,  I  did say in a comic

Comment: @AncientSwordRage I know! I did not hope for this answer to be the chosen one ! ;)